# why is $H^{⊗2}$ used to denote the parallel action of two Hadamard gates?

Tags: linear-algebra, hadamard

Why is the tensor product used here, what's its meaning? I learned tensor products as an operation between 2 matrices, and have an effect such as the follows:
[image]

How does the tensor product above relate to the tensor product in $H^{⊗2}$?

Comment: Please do not use images for mathematical formulas. This prevents them from scaling with other content, makes them unsearchable and hurts site's accessibility. QCSE supports MathJax. Please make use of it for your formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use $H^{\otimes n}$ as a shorthand for $H\otimes H\otimes H\otimes\ldots\otimes H$ (repeated $n$ times), where each $\otimes$ is applied just as you've learned it.

This is in the same way that you'd use $x^n$ as a shorthand for $x\times x\times x\times\ldots\times x$ repeated $n$ times.